# Test whether a number is equal to the multiplication of 2 successive Fibonacci numbers

Tags: javascript

Here is a link to [the challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5541f58a944b85ce6d00006a/train/javascript).

Basically, the task is to test whether a randomly passed number is equal to the multiplication of 2 successive Fibonacci.

```
function productFib(prod) {
    var x = []
    var z;

    var a = 0
    var b = 1
    var c = 7
    var h = 1000
    while (c < 100) {
        var t = a + b
        var a = b
        var b = t
        x.push(t)
        c++
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        if (prod = x[i] * x[i + 1]) {
            z = [x[i], x[i + 1], true]
        } else {
            z = [x[i], x[i + 1], false]
        }
    }
    return z
}
```

First, I am creating a function which generates Fibonacci numbers and then I am passing them to an array. This is tested, so I guess the problem is not there. Then I try to create a for loop which will multiply every 2 numbers and then check whether they are equal to the random number.

At least that is my idea, but I keep getting results like - `[1, 2, true]` or `[undefined]` every single time.

Comment: `prod = x[i]*x[i+1]` should probably be using `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: Yes, I completely forgot - Thank you. I am still not able to understand how to overwrite(set the value of z) - guess that is the reason for returning undefined

Comment: You are overwriting `z` on every iteration in that second loop. It might well have had a value with `true` at one time, but you still return one with `false`.

Comment: You should try to find a solution that doesn't need an array at all.

Comment: You probably don't want the `var` keywords inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but please use relevant names for variables.

Answer (score -1):

This code works:

```
function productFib(prod){
    var x = []
    var z;

    var a = 0
    var b = 1
    var c = 0
    var h = 1000
    var t=0

    //Edited the loop to only check numbers below the one you are looking
    // to make(prod) because any two consecutive numbers over that will not produce the 
    // number you are looking for(14*any number above that cannot make 13)
    while( t < prod){
        //removed c++
        t = a + b
        var a = b
        var b = t
        x.push(t)
   }
   //Set the loop to loop through the whole array(x.length)
   for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        if(prod == x[i]*x[i+1]){ //Added a double equals sign
            z =[x[i], x[i+1], true]
            //For testing
            console.log(x[i] + ' and '+x[i+1] + ' make ' + prod)

            //Return the number when one is found, not after looking through
            //the whole array
            return z
        }
     }
   //In case none are found
   return false
 }
 productFib(4895) //this is the multiplication of 89 and 55, successive fib's
```

A demo is here: https://jsfiddle.net/qrq3zh7j/3/

The changes are detailed in the comments

Comment: Why do you do `t=true` and then `t =a + b`?  What do you intend `t` to be?  Why are you still doing `c++` even though it's not being used anywhere?

Comment: I was trying to maintain the OP's code as much as I could so he could see what was going on.

Comment: First! Thank you very much. In this exercise - IF it is false i have to return the same array with the same number, but with "false" instead of "true"..Expected: '[89, 144, false]', instead got: 'false' - any idea how to do that?